# What happens if the Intelligence of an undead affected by the Necromancy wizard's Command Undead feature changes after it gets controlled?

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, wizard, undead, ability-scores

[This question asked about the impact of Feebleminding an undead before using the School of Necromancy wizard's Command Undead feature](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/130108/does-feeblemind-change-the-effect-of-command-undead-on-high-intelligence-targets); it seems that this would be an effective tactic for making an undead easier to control.

I have a follow-up question:
What happens if the undead loses the Feeblemind effect while still affected by Command Undead?

Specifically, the [Necromancy wizard](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/wizard#SchoolofNecromancy)'s Command Undead feature (PHB, p. 119) says:

> If the target has an Intelligence of 8 or higher, it has advantage on
>   the saving throw. If it fails the saving throw and has an Intelligence
>   of 12 or higher, it can repeat the saving throw at the end of every
>   hour until it succeeds and breaks free.

They succeed the 30-day save vs Feeblemind, or the wizard chooses to break the Feeblemind enchantment using one of the specified ways to break it.

Once their Intelligence score reverts to 12 or higher, do they get to start doing a save vs. Command Undead every hour? Or are they still affected by it indefinitely because they had an Int score below 12 when they first made the save?

Similarly, what if you used Command Undead on a naturally low-Int undead, and then artificially raised its Int score above 12 (e.g. using a Headband of Intellect or a similar item)?

Comment: not sure why someone voted to close as unclear. OP is basically asking what happens if you "command undead" a creature affected by Feeblemind, and the target later recovers from Feeblemind while still being affected by command undead. Since creatures with high INT have an easier time resisting Command Undead, it's certainly valid to ask what happens in this case.

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance.

Answer (score 8):

### RAW, the sudden gaining of Intelligence would have no effect

The initial saving throw against Command Undead is made when you use the feature, and by a strict reading of the wording, the consequence of failure and the ability to repeat the save would apply at the time of this *initial* save.

> If it fails the saving throw and has an Intelligence of 12 or higher,
>   it can repeat the saving throw at the end of every hour until it
>   succeeds and breaks free.

i.e. If [fails save and Int 12 or higher] then [able to repeat save]. Once you are past this point, the undead's intelligence doesn't matter.

### However...

Logically it makes sense that if an undead suddenly gained Intelligence it might have a chance to break free, but this would be entirely up to DM fiat.